# What is the name of the Mac OS X text editor that uses a green and yellow lotus flower icon?

Tags: macos, mac, text-editing

I'm pretty sure there's a Mac text editor out there that uses a green and yellow lotus flower as it's icon but I cannot seem to remember the name. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: +1 - Useful question - Jeff Geerling had a memory lapse that prompted me to search for the same application: [Kubernetes 101 - Episode 6 - DNS, TLS, Cron, Logging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1_uINjq2As) at [19:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1_uINjq2As&t=1155). At least, I think that it is the same application to which he is referring...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it [this one](http://versionsapp.com/)?

This is not a text editor, this is a SVN client. It's name is Versions.

Comment: Yes! And you're right, not a text editor. Makes sense why I couldn't find it on my own :) Thanks!